# Exception about bcrypt.dll when instantiating a MD5CryptoServiceProvider

Tags: encryption, .net-4.0, md5

We use a MD5 hashing algorithm in our app. One of our users gets the following exception on the line

```
Dim hasher=new MD5CryptoServiceProvider
```

The Exception states (in dutch)

> Exception: System.DllNotFoundException; Source Kan DLL bcrypt.dll niet laden: Ongeldige toegang tot geheugenlocatie. (Uitzondering van HRESULT: 0x800703E6); Message:    bij Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.BCryptGetFipsAlgorithmMode(Boolean& pfEnabled)
>      bij System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoConfig.get_AllowOnlyFipsAlgorithms()
>      bij System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider..ctor()

Which means that the brcrypt.dll cannot be loaded because of an invalid access to the memory location.

The brcrypt.dll is present in the user's Sytem32 folder.

What is happening here?

Comment: have you tried replacing the DLL?

Comment: the Exception says the DLL was not found, you found it in system32 ... can you replace the DLL file with a known-good version? (maybe from another machine) ... if the machine has a windows 64bit version installed, make sure to place 32 bit DLLs that belong into system32, into sysWOW64 instead ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The customer's computer crashed soon afterwards and had to be repaired. Windows was reinstalled. The problem was gone.